# Reactjs OnClick Add More List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

https://jsbin.com/boluqeqewu/edit?html,js,console,output

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.data = props.data;
    }
  addMore  = () => {
    let data = this.data;
        size = data.length + 1;
        data.push(size);

        this.data = data;
        console.log(data);

  }
  render = () => {
    let data = this.props.data;
    console.log(data);
    return (
       <div> 
        <button onClick={() => this.addMore()}>ClickMe</button>
        <ul> 
        {data.map((i) =>     
           <li>{i}</li>
        )}        
       </ul>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

let data =[1,2,3];
                ReactDOM.render(
                <App data={data} />,
                document.getElementById("container"),
                  );
```

When i click `ClickMe` Button i want do add more `li`s. Im changing the data variable of the class but how do i change the dom or render it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updating and manipulate `dom` in `React` you should store you data in `state` and change one with `setState` method. React will automatically invoke `render` method, when you call `setState`

[example](https://jsbin.com/jaqezucuja/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        // save data in state
        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        };
    }
    addMore  = () => {
        const data = this.state.data;
        size = data.length + 1;
        data.push(size);

        // udate data in state
        // will automatically call render method after update 
        this.setState({data});
    }
    render = () => {
        // get data from state, not from props
        const data = this.state.data;
        return (
            <div> 
                <button onClick={this.addMore}>ClickMe</button>
                <ul> 
                    {data.map(i => <li key={i}>{i}</li> )}        
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

let data =[1,2,3];
ReactDOM.render(
    <App data={data} />,
    document.getElementById("container"),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes to component state will trigger a re-rendering, so if you have data you want to modify and have that rendered to the DOM again, then you can add data to the state in the constructor:

```
this.state = {data: props.data}
```

You can change it in your addMore method using setState:

```
this.setState({data: newdata})
```

Refer to the React docs on state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html